# How to get the full collection of listbox, when i tap on the button, which is in listbox's item?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have a collection which shows in listbox. It's a listBoxItem of major listBox. Each listbox's item(not major) has a textbox and button. So, i need to get all collection when I tap on any button in listbox. 
This is windows pnone 7 application. I want to get a list of items that are in listbBox.
I know how to get one item if it's not a collection(just item of major listBox)

```
        private void Audio_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uri = null;
        TextBox tb = null;
        var grid = (Grid)((Button)sender).Parent;
        foreach (var child in grid.Children)
        {
            if (child is TextBox && (string)((TextBox)child).Tag == "URL")
            {
                tb = (TextBox)child;
            }
        }
        uri = tb.Text;
```

but i dont know how to get all the items. The problem is in that the "sender" has type button, not a listBoxItem. And anyway, if it had type listBoxItem - i'm not sure i understand how to make a list of items(

Or maybe i can use another control, with out scrolling? collection is not very big. But i think i'll have the same problem(

Update:

```
                                <local:NewsTemplateSelector.Audio>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Name="AudioGrid" MaxHeight="2000">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Width="75"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Texts}"  Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" />
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Photo[0].Big}" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Audio[0].Title}"  Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" Margin="96,10,10,10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
                                        <Button Background="Black"  Content="Play" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,7,0,10" Grid.Row="3" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Width="74" Tap="Audio_Button_Click" />
                                        <Image Source="images\like.jpg" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="4" Width="30" Margin="0,1.5,34,-1.5" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Likes}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="4" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="30" Margin="0,0.5,0,-0.5"/>
                                        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="420" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1"  />
                                        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="80" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" />
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Audio[0].Url}" Tag="URL" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:NewsTemplateSelector.Audio>
```

and

```
  <local:NewsTemplateSelector.Audios>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Name="AudiosGrid" MaxHeight="2000">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Width="75"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Texts}"  Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" />
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Photo[0].Big}" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <ListBox Name="audiosListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Audio}"  MaxHeight="500" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" >
                                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25"  />
                                                        <Button Content="Play" Background="Black" Tap="Audios_Button_Click" />
                                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Audio.Url}" Tag="URL" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListBox>

                                        <Image Source="images\like.jpg" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="4" Width="30" Margin="0,1.5,34,-1.5" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Likes}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="4" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="30" Margin="0,0.5,0,-0.5"/>
                                        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="420" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1"  />
                                        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="80" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:NewsTemplateSelector.Audios>
```

I have [image: Collection]

[image: Simple]

Comment: can you please show the existing code that you have and clarify if this is in C# winforms or wpf etc..are you wanting to get a list of all items that are in the ListBox..? please clean up your question and make it more clear as to what you are looking for

Comment: There are 2 ways that I can think of.. your for loop for the Grid I think should be done differently..

Comment: updated one more time, sorry, now i belive you can understand what i have and what i want)

Comment: uri = tb.Text; you want that assigned for each Tb.Text..? then you need to move that inside your Foreach Loop

Comment: notice in the ClearTextItems method that I wrote I am checking for different type of Control.. you can use this to do the same type of thing.. I hope this makes sense

Comment: uri = tb.Text; you want that assigned for each Tb.Text..? then you need to move that inside your Foreach Loop   - but how can i get a collection for foreach in Button_Click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Linq To Visual Tree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) ([download code](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/LinqToTree.zip), just one file) to get the Listbox that holds all the items. This code on the click handler should work for it.

```
var parentLb = ((Button)sender).Ancestors().FirstOrDefault(x => x is Listbox) as Listbox;
if(parentLb != null)
{
    // Cast the ItemsSource property to the list type you're using...
    var list = parentLb.ItemsSource
    // And do whatever you want with that list.
}
```

You should of course cast `list` to its original type.

Comment: var list = parentLb.ItemsSource writes an error "System.Windows.DependencyObject" do not have defiftion for "ItemsSource" and extension method "ItemsSource" was not found

Comment: Whoops, forgot the cast on parentLb. Edited the code, try now